# The image of injective Holomorphic function is onto?

Tags: complex-analysis

Actually, I want to prove that The image of injective entire function is $\mathbb C$.

Moreover, I want to prove more general case.

I proved Holomorphic image is Dense.

How can I proceed more?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem

Comment: @PeteL.Clark But That implies only density.(Picard's little theorem also says that). Injectivity may kill the point $f$ never hit, I guess...

Comment: No, it says that every value, except possibly one, is assumed *infinitely many times*, which prevents injectivity.

Comment: Aha, Picard's "GREAT" Theorem. Ok. Essential singularity at infinity, Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  But in fact with a little more work one can use the Casorati-Weierstrass Throem, as in Ranc's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is holomorphic, and injective implies $f' \neq 0$ (otherwise injectivity will be lost). So IFT ( inverse function theorem) implies $f$ is locally homeomorphism. Now $f$ is injective and  and local homeomorphsim, which implies $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. Picard's theorem says that $f$ can missed atmost one point. But if $f$ is not $\mathbb C$, then image of $f$ is not simple connected (contradiction). So image has to be $\mathbb C$.

Comment: What does mean IFT?

Comment: Inverse function theorem

Comment: $f$ can miss At most 1 point, Right?

Comment: does not matter, in any case, image will not be simply connected

Comment: @nicksohn edited...did you get my proof?

Comment: Yes, Doesn't matter. Just Check What I thought. And yes, This is truely elegant way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We need 3.5 theorems for this:
**Open map**:Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open domain $U$ then $f(U)$ is open. 
**Casorati-weirstrass**: Suppose $f$ is holomorphic and non constant in a punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$. then we have the following options
(1) $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} f(z)$ exists (posibily $\infty$)
(2) The image of $f(z)$ on every punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ 
**Liouville THM**: A function that is entire and holomorphic must be constant.
**corollarity of Liouville THM**: If $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z) = \infty$ Then $f$ is a polynomial.

Our problem: $f(z)$ is entire and 1-1.
From open map theorem we understand that the image of $f$ over the unit disc is open.

Now let us understand the behavior of $f$ near $\infty$.
 From Casorati-Weirstrass:
The limit must exist because if not, then the image of any neighbourhood of $\infty$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ and so must intersect the image of the unit disc. This is contradictory to $f$ being 1-1.
The limit can't be a constant because then $f$ is bounded and entire, thus it is constant (Liouville THM). Again, this is contradictory to 1-1'ness.
Then we understand the limit must be $\infty$ and so $f$ must be a polynom.

A polynom which is 1-1 (in $\mathbb C$) must be of the form $az+b$, which is also surjective.

Comment: It's worth noting that any polynomial from $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$ is injective iff it is subjective. This is known as the Axe-Grothendik Theorem and is probably my favorite proof in all of mathematics.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks, I didn't know that. Also, what is a polynomial *to* $\mathbb C^n$? Does it mean it's a polynomial in every coordinate?

Comment: Sorry it's Ax–Grothendieck, I'm bad at spelling names. And yes, it's a function where each coordinate is a multi variate polynomial.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Alright, But the assumption of Ax-Gro thm is Holomorphic function is polynomial.

Comment: Partially through the above answer, it is concluded that the function must be a polynomial. That's why I left it as a note on this answer, as an alternative way to conclude.