# Injective holomorphic function is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis

I know my problem is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596206/the-image-of-injective-holomorphic-function-is-onto), but I'm not allowed to use Picard's theorem here, so this question does not answer mine. Also, I'm looking to finish the proof I've already started.

> Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an injective holomorphic function. I want to prove $f$ is surjective.

We know any holomorphic function has its image dense in $\mathbb{C}$ and since $f$ is injective we also have $f' \neq 0$ which means, by the inverse function theorem, that there is a neighborhood around each point in which $f$ is invertible.

I want to show this inverse is the same for all points in the plane, that is we have a unique inverse of $f$ making it bijective. I'm stuck here.

Any idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I will prove the following assertion.

> Let $f$ be an injective entire function, then $f$ is linear. Certainly $f$ is also surjective.

**Proof.** Suppose $f(0)=w_0\in\mathbb C$. By the open mapping theorem, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(w_0)\subset f(B_1(0))$, so that $\frac{1}{f(z)-w_0}$ is bounded on $\mathbb C\setminus B_1(0)$. On the other hand, since $\frac{z}{f(z)-w_0}$ is an entire function  (by the injectivity of $f$), we have
$$\left|\frac{z}{f(z)-w_0}\right|\leqslant A|z|+B\quad\text{for some }A,B>0.$$
Then you can deduce that $\frac{z}{f(z)-w_0}$ is a linear function by Cauchy's integral formula, thus $f$ can be written as $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. But $f$ has no poles on $\mathbb C$, so $f$ is linear.

*Remark.* This also proves that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb C)=\{z\mapsto az+b:a\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},b\in\mathbb C\}$.